# Sending response multiple times. Nodemailer/singup

Tags: node.js, api, nodemailer

I am implementing otp verification which is sent to email with nodemailer. I know the error that I am getting two responses from *registerUser*, but don't know the right way to integrate *sendOTPVerificationEmail* with *registerUser*. Should I use another route for sending email or there is way to fix my code below.

**userController.js**

```
export const registerUser = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const { name, email, password } = req.body;
  const userExist = await User.findOne({ email });

  if (userExist) {
    res.status(400);
    throw new Error('User already Exists');
  }

  const user = await User.create({
    name,
    email,
    password,
    verified: false,
  });

  user
    .save()
    .then((result) => {
      sendOTPVerificationEmail(result, res)
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
      res.json({
        status: 'Failed',
        message: 'An error occured while saving account!',
      });
    });

  if (user) {
    res.status(201).send({
      _id: user._id,
      email: user.email,
      name: user.name,
      isAdmin: user.isAdmin,
      verified: false,
      token: generateToken(user._id),
    });
  } else {
    res.status(400);
    throw new Error('Invalid user data');
  }
});

const sendOTPVerificationEmail = async ({ _id, email }, res) => {
  try {
    const otp = `${Math.floor(1000 + Math.random * 9000)}`;

    const mailOptions = {
      from: process.env.AUTH_EMAIL,
      to: email,
      subject: 'Verify Your Email',
      html: `<p>Enter this <b>${otp}<b> to verify your email address to complete the sign up!</p>
      <p>This code <b>expires in 1 hour</b></p>`,
    };

    const newOTPVerification = await new UserOTPVerification({
      userId: _id,
      otp: otp,
      createdAt: Date.now(),
      expiresAt: Date.now() + 3600000,
    });

    await newOTPVerification.save();

    const accessToken = await oAuth2Client.getAccessToken();

    let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
      service: 'gmail',
      auth: {
        type: 'OAuth2',
        user: process.env.AUTH_EMAIL,
        pass: process.env.AUTH_PASS,
        clientId: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
        refreshToken: process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN,
        accessToken: accessToken,
      },
    });

    transporter.verify((error, success) => {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error);
      } else {
        console.log('Ready for messages!');
        console.log(success);
      }
    });

    await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);

    res.json({
      status: 'Pending...',
      message: 'Verification OTP email is sent!',
      data: {
        userId: _id,
        email,
      },
    });

  } catch (error) {
    res.json({
      status: 'Failed',
      message: error.message,
    });
  }
};
```